# How can I prevent the Explorer View from opening when opening a Remote-SSH window in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

When opening (or reopening) a Remote-SSH window in VS Code, the side bar is always expanded with the Explorer showing an "open folder" button. Is it possible to not show the sidebar upon login?